# How to verify my account?

Tags: facebook, verification, account

I have a fbk account verified by phone (with sms code). 
I'm trying to create a new application and I always get this  dialog

[image: App creation failed]

I followed the link on the bottom (https://www.facebook.com/help/contact_us.php?id=140703502680919) and uploaded a photo of my ID, but I still get this and can not create application.

I'm using my real name in my profile.

Any ideas what is wrong and what else to do to verify my account?

thank you

Comment: I would also like to know what is up with this message. Facebook's support channels sure aren't any help. Seems like they really, _really_ don't want developers to work with their platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A week after uploading my photo ID my account was verified and I can now create apps and use the Graph API

Answer (score 0):

recheck your email address & confirm it

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are not a verified facebook user.For creating an application in facebook the user must be verified either via phone or email.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook requires to verify yourself either with your phone or credit card before it lets you to be a developer. i.e., to create new apps. if you have already verified via mobile, then wait for 24hrs from the time you entered the confirmation code.